# Powershell ScriptProperty to check Path

Tags: powershell, window

Please can some one explain how to use Powershell `ScriptProperty`.

I've checked few tutorials but got information about the `-property` only.
*I am trying to check via powershell Process Path.*

So am checking `get-process | get-member`
And I got a lot of `MemberTypes`: Method, Property, NoteProperty, ScriptProperty

But I can't figure out how to use `ScriptProperty`.

Trying to : `Get-Process -Name bits| get-member -membertype scriptproperty | select-object scriptproperty Path` 
But I getting this error:

```
    Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Path'.
At line:1 char:65
+ Get-Process -Name bits| get-member -membertype scriptproperty | select-object sc ...
+                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

Example:(sorry for my english)
Want to try define path for notepad++ process, I am trying to check path for process, for example if you using notepad++ and if i will try to use that command:
Get-Process -Name notepad++| get-member -membertype scriptproperty | Where-Object Name -eq Path and it not providing the process path, only such output :

```
       TypeName: System.Diagnostics.Process

Name MemberType     Definition
---- ----------     ----------
Path ScriptProperty System.Object Path {get=$this.Mainmodule.FileName;}
```

How should i use the scriptproperty command to get process path? (I really do not understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to select the `ScriptProperty` where the the `Name` *equals* `Path`. So you are looking for the [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) cmdlet:

```
Get-Process -Name bits | get-member -membertype scriptproperty  | Where-Object Name -eq Path
```

---

But beside that, what do you want to? I feel like you don't need the `Get-Member` cmdlet here...

**Answer to your comment:**
You want to retrieve the `Path` of a process, so you don't need to hassle with a `ScriptProperty`, just select it:

```
Get-Process -Name bits | Select Path
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response, I want to understand how to use the ScriptProperty and got an output, I've updated main area with explanaition what i am trying to achieve. as i got such scriptproperty, but can't get an output which i expect to get. My expectations was path to the process. Path i believe should be as in the gui in (windows task manager> process>openFileLocation)

Comment: Yes, you are right! :) it is working, so basicaly it does not have any difrence i can use it as simple property ? as i was confused then i saw scuh explanaition: ScriptProperty System.Object Path {get=$this.Mainmodule.FileName;}

Comment: Yes, you can use it as a simple property. You can use the `Get-Member` property once to see what properties / method some object expose and then omit it and just select it...